# IPython.display issues in Pycharm (Matplotlib 3.0 Cookbook)

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I am trying to plot a correlation matrix using the object-oriented API instead of pyplot, but can't seem to get IPython.display to display a proper correlation map as shown in the MatPlotLib 3.0 Cookbook. I am using PyCharm IDE versus the recommended Jupyter.

Here is my current code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from IPython.display import display

wine_quality = pd.read_csv('Matplotlib-3.0-Cookbook-master/Chapter02/winequality.csv', delimiter=';')

corr = wine_quality.corr()

fig = Figure(figsize=(12, 9))

FigureCanvas(fig)

axs = fig.add_subplot(111)
corimage = axs.imshow(corr, cmap='hot')
fig.colorbar(corimage)

fontd = {'fontsize': 10,
         'fontweight': 'bold',
         'rotation': 45}

axs.set(xticks=range(len(corr)), yticks=range(len(corr)),
        title='Correlation Matrix')
axs.set_xticklabels(corr.columns, fontdict=fontd)
axs.set_xticklabels(corr.columns)

display(fig)
```

Output:

```
Figure(1200x900)
```

Comment: Try `plt.show()` instead of `display(fig)`

Comment: I keep getting this error when I try to run it, including trying the plt.show():

DeprecationWarning: Importing display from IPython.core.display is deprecated since IPython 7.14, please import from IPython display
  from IPython.core.display import display